# Как работают сущности, добавленные внутри программы с помощью AddScope, при вызове их внутри программы

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Доброго времени суток.

Использую ASP.NET Core 2.1

Я знаю, что сущности, добавленные AddScope, создаются при каждом запросе к ним со стороны страницы.

Вопрос: так же ли работают эти сущности при вызове их внутри кода? Допустим если я их принимаю в конструкторе по DI, а потом вызываю методы этой сущности. Будет ли это работать так же?(по моим ощущениям нет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы создаете объект через AddScope(), то вам будет возвращаться каждый раз **тот же самый объект** что и вы получили в конструкторе. Например

```
class SimpleClass
{
  public int Field;
}
//Класс Startup
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddScoped<SimpleClass>();
}
//Вызов в контроллере
public class HomeController : Controller
{        
    SimpleClass SimpleClassInstance { get; }        
    public HomeController(SimpleClass simpleClass)
    {
        SimpleClassInstance = simpleClass;
        SimpleClassInstance.Field++;// Здесь SimpleClassInstance.Field == 1
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        SimpleClassInstance.Field++;// Здесь SimpleClassInstance.Field == 2
       return Content($"{SimpleClassInstance.Field}"); 
    }
}
```

Если вы хотите получать **новый объект** при **каждом обращении** к \тому объекту, то используйте AddTransient() вместо AddScope()

Comment: здесь ещё неплохо описано https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/6.2.php